# Premature end of document qt, xml

Tags: xml, qt, xsd, xml-parsing

What is wrong with this xsd file?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="root" type="rootType"/>
  <xs:complexType name="twokindType">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="name"/>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:int" name="n"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="twoType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="twokindType" name="twokind"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="name"/>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="number"/>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="vendorType">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="name" use="optional"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="priceType">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="name" use="optional"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="oneType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="vendorType" name="vendor"/>
      <xs:element type="priceType" name="price"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="name" use="optional"/>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="n" use="optional"/>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="onesType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="oneType" name="one" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="name"/>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="number"/>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="rootType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="twoType" name="two"/>
      <xs:element type="onesType" name="ones"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

I have checked its validity on different websites and they all say it's okay. I took a code sample from qt's website to load it, and I get an error saying "Premature end of document." The error is on line 1, column 0. I don't see anything wrong there. I looked at this file using hex editor and there are no weird symbols.

Below is the code from qt's website:

```
QUrl schemaUrl("file:///home/user/schema.xsd");

    QXmlSchema schema;
    schema.load(schemaUrl);

    if (schema.isValid()) {
        QFile file("test.xml");
        file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);

        QXmlSchemaValidator validator(schema);
        if (validator.validate(&file, QUrl::fromLocalFile(file.fileName())))
            qDebug() << "instance document is valid";
        else
            qDebug() << "instance document is invalid";
    }
```

Comment: may be error in xml file?

Comment: @AlexMuravyov did you read what I said at all?

Comment: Please show the XML document `test.xml`. Thanks.

Comment: @MathiasMüller the problem is not with the xml file, the problem is that this program doesn't load the .xsd file! The xml file has nothing to do with it, if you think that it doesn't match the schema, it does, I used online tools to check  its validity. The program fails precisely when schema.isValid() is called. The part where I do QFile file("test.xml") is not even reached.

Answer (score 2):

My experience is that "Premature end of document" indicates that loaded definition is empty. So schemaUrl variable does not indicates the right file, even if "/home/user/schema.xsd" exists in your file system.
Try following:

```
schema.load(QUrl::fromLocalFile(QString("/home/user/schema.xsd")));
```

or defind schemaUrl variable as follows:

```
QUrl schemaUrl(QString("file:///home/user/schema.xsd"));
```

This always works in my code.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and managed to work around it simply by using this overload

```
bool QXmlSchemaValidator::validate(const QUrl &source) const
```

of the QXmlSchemaValidator::validate() function, rather than the one you use:

```
bool QXmlSchemaValidator::validate(QIODevice *source, const QUrl &documentUri = QUrl()) const
```

In your case:

```
QUrl schemaUrl("file:///home/user/schema.xsd");

QXmlSchema schema;
schema.load(schemaUrl);

if (schema.isValid()) {
    QFile file("test.xml");

    QXmlSchemaValidator validator(schema);
    if (validator.validate(QUrl::fromLocalFile(file.fileName())))
        qDebug() << "instance document is valid";
    else
        qDebug() << "instance document is invalid";
}
```